# Using the five lemma in proving $H_{n}(D^k, D^k \setminus \{0\} ) \cong H_{n}(D^k, S^{k - 1}).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, proof-writing, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I want to show that for all $n,$ $H_{n}(D^k, D^k \setminus \{0\} ) \cong H_{n}(D^k, S^{k-1} ).$

**My trial is:**

1-I know that $D^k \setminus \{0\}$ is homotopically equivalent to S^{k-1}, but I do not know how this is helpful here. Also, I do not know how to create the two rows of exact sequences of abelian groups and why my diagram will commute if I am going to use the 5-lemma, could anyone explain this for me, please?

Could anyone help me answer those questions?

2- Also it is not clear for me when should I think that I should create a long exact sequence and when should I think that I should apply the 5-lemma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only tools that we have in basic topology for dealing with relative homology groups are the long exact sequence of a pair and for good pairs the isomorphism $H_n(X,A)\cong \bar{H}(X/A) $. You are interested in the relationship between two relative homology groups and there is an obvious relative map between the two. Relative maps give maps of the long exact sequence of a pair. This would be a good thing to apply the five lemma to.

Comment: what is this obvious relative map?

Comment: why $D - *$ is included in boundary D?

Comment: Sorry, other way around $(D,\partial D) \rightarrow (D,D-*)$.A map of pairs should  send the first into the first and the second into the second.

Comment: Could you please look at this question for me (if you do not mind)? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436302/why-the-diagram-commutes

Answer (score 1):

You probably know that we have a long exact sequence of the form:

$... \rightarrow H_n(A) \rightarrow H_n(X) \rightarrow H_n(X,A) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(A) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(X)\rightarrow ...$

You probably know that $D^{k} - \{0\}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{k-1}$, and therefore $H_n(D^{k} - \{0\}) \cong H_n(S^{k-1})$.

So you have two long exact sequences:

$... \rightarrow H_n(D^{k}-\{0\}) \rightarrow H_n(D^{k}) \rightarrow H_n(D^{k},D^{k}-\{0\}) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(D^{k} - \{0\}) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(D^{k})\rightarrow ...$

$... \rightarrow H_n(S^{k-1}) \rightarrow H_n(D^{k}) \rightarrow H_n(D^{k},S^{k-1}) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(S^{k-1}) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(D^{k})\rightarrow ...$

The outwards arrows are isomorphisms, therefore by the $5$ lemma, so is $H_n(D^{k},S^{k-1}) \cong H_n(D^{k},D^{k} - \{0\}) $

Comment: And why we are sure that our groups are abelian? why we are sure that the diagram commutes?

Comment: I know now why our groups are abelian, but still I do not know why the diagram commutes, could you please explain this for me

Comment: Why homotopy equivalence implies isomorphism between homology groups?

Comment: And how do I decide in my commutative diagram which long exact sequence should be above and which long exact sequence should be below?

Comment: maybe I should take into account that the circle is included inside the punctured disk?